# Shopify PUT API call with long html content

Tags: php, shopify, put, shopify-app, shopify-api

is there an option to create new section by sending file content using the shopify api?
i want to include the content of certain file instead of writing it all under the value tag on my call.
how can i create a new section that has long code and schema as well

```
PUT /admin/api/2021-01/themes/828155753/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "templates/index.liquid",
    "value": "<img src='backsoon-postit.png'><p>We are busy updating the store for you and will be back within the hour.</p>"
  }
}
```

i tested the following option but it is not working properly:

```
$asset_file = array(
  "asset" => array (
    "key" => "sections/radd.liquid",
    "value" => file_get_contents("test.txt")
  )
);
```

this is the content of my test file:

```
<div id="flx"></div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "story",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "section_title",
      "label": {
        "cs": "Nadpis",
        "da": "Overskrift",
        "de": "Titel",
        "en": "Heading",
        "es": "Título",
        "fi": "Otsake",
        "fr": "En-tête",
        "it": "Heading",
        "ja": "見出し",
        "ko": "제목",
        "nb": "Overskrift",
        "nl": "Kop",
        "pl": "Nagłówek",
        "pt-BR": "Título",
        "pt-PT": "Título",
        "sv": "Rubrik",
        "th": "ส่วนหัว",
        "tr": "Başlık",
        "vi": "Tiêu đề",
        "zh-CN": "标题",
        "zh-TW": "標題"
      }
    }
   ],"presets": [
    {
      "name": "story",
      "category": {
        "cs": "Pokročilé rozvržení",
        "da": "Avanceret layout",
        "de": "Komplizierteres Layout",
        "en": "Advanced layout",
        "es": "Diseño avanzado",
        "fi": "Monimutkaisempi layout",
        "fr": "Mise en page avancée",
        "it": "Layout avanzato",
        "ja": "高度なレイアウト",
        "ko": "고급 레이아웃",
        "nb": "Avansert oppsett",
        "nl": "Geavanceerde opmaak",
        "pl": "Zaawansowany układ",
        "pt-BR": "Layout avançado",
        "pt-PT": "Esquema avançado",
        "sv": "Avancerad layout",
        "th": "เลย์เอาท์ขั้นสูง",
        "tr": "Gelişmiş düzen",
        "vi": "Bố cục nâng cao",
        "zh-CN": "高级布局",
        "zh-TW": "進階版面配置"
      }
    }
 ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: I think you create a file on your server and upload it using asset API, is easier rather than write.

Comment: Yep @Onkar is right, a theme section is considered an asset, [this endpoint](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset) should help.

Comment: @KarimTarek i am using assets api, you can see that i am doing PUT call to assets.json

Comment: What is the error you're getting back from Shopify? The way you upload a file like this is to pass a string for the value. Are you sure test.txt is reading properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet in Ruby should shed more light into this

```rb
def add_theme_code_snippet(theme_id:, type:, name:, code:)
    options = {
      query: {
        asset: {
          key: "#{type.downcase}s/#{name}.liquid",
          value: code
        }
      },
      basic_auth: basic_auth
    }

    res = HTTParty.put( "#{shopify_shop_api_url}/themes/#{theme_id}/assets.json", options )
    handle_shopify_response(response: res)
end
```

To upload a section, the key of the asset (aka. file name) need to include the name of the directory of the code snippet type you are uploading, for example if I'm uploading a code snippet named `boo` to the `snippets` directory the key (file name) of the asset I'm sending to the API should be `snippets/boo.liquid` in your case you want to send a section, then you should include `sections/` in your asset key attribute/property, so it looks like `sections/file_name.liquid`.

Happy hacking!